# MVC jquery calling a controller method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to populate one drop down list based on the selection of another drop down list.

I know it's a fairly common problem, and for two whole days I've been trying different samples that I find on the net, to no avail!

Here is my code:

controller:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> listTestCases(string id)
    {
        IQueryable<SelectListItem> A = repository.listTestCases(id);
        return (A.toList());
    }

    public JsonResult listTestCases_2(string id)
    {
        IQueryable<SelectListItem> A = repository.listTestCases(id);
        return Json(A);
    }
```

I have two methods, one of them returns a List, the other one JSONResults, and I tried everything I found on the net with both methods.
script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#testCategoriesUniqueId').change(function() {

        var testCategory = $(this).val();
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        alert(testCategory);

        $.getJSON("TestInput/listTestCases/" ,  {id: testCategory}, function(data) {
            alert("here");
        });

    });
});
```

With the above code, the code goes through the listTestCases, and get's the results, but It doesn't go to the success function. (doesn't alert)

I have tried:

```
 $.getJSON("TestInput/listTestCases/" + testCategory, null, function(data) {
            alert("here");
        });
```

not surprisingly same results.

I even tried : (json-p)

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "TestInput/listTestCases/" + testCategory,
            dataType: "json-p",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.length);
                var S = "";
                $("#testCasesUniqueId").removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    S += data[i];
                    var val = data[i].Value;
                    var text = data[i].Text;
                    $("#testCasesUniqueId").addOption(val, text, false);
                }
                alert(S);
            }
        }
        );
```

and the result is a string (System.collections.List[...SelectListItem]. and does not give me the objects of the list. so I tried it with listTestCases2, and it is not even calling the method.

I read somewhere that I need to use post instead of get, and I even tried postJSON. and no result.

Basically I'm super lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere I read that I need to use "post" method for my purpose.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "TestInput/listTestCases_2/" + testCategory,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.length);

            }
        });
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference your ajax calls from the web root (preface the url with '/'). As written, you are referencing the call relatively. I'd recommend against using double quotes in jquery/javascript. Also, don't mix results types.  Assuming your controller is TestInput, try:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/TestInput/listTestCases_2/' + testCategory,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.length);
            var S = '';
            $('#testCasesUniqueId').removeOption(/./);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                S += data[i];
                var val = data[i].Value;
                var text = data[i].Text;
                $('#testCasesUniqueId').addOption(val, text, false);
            }
            alert(S);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you shouldn't hard code the url and you shouldn't hardcode the url to start with '/'. when you do that you are assuming that the website will always run as the root webiste of the domain which is often not the case. even if it will run that way in production, it limits your ability to stand up a test site in a virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your parameter `testCategory` in using the `data:` setting of the `$.ajax` call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "TestInput/listTestCases",
            data: { id: testCategory },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.length);
                var S = "";
                $("#testCasesUniqueId").removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    S += data[i];
                    var val = data[i].Value;
                    var text = data[i].Text;
                    $("#testCasesUniqueId").addOption(val, text, false);
                }
                alert(S);
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: but when I use json-p, it gives me the string ((System.collections.List[...SelectListItem]) asthe result (S)

Comment: so if you change it to json-p, you get into the success?

Comment: json-p treats it as if it comes from another server, so instead of a reference to the object, I get a string which is the object type